# Move subview up when keyboard displayed over textfields in subview

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have two textfields inside a subview and i am trying to move subview up when any of textfield clicked inside subview and keyboard appears. The problem is subview moves down when subview is up and i clicked on second textfield. It should hide when I touch any of the view except textfields.

The definition of my two textfield and subview;

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginView: UIView!
```

The code in viewDidLoad

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

And two other functions which show and hide keyboard

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if loginView.frame.origin.y == 0{
            let height = keyboardSize.height

            self.loginView.frame.origin.y += height
        }

    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {


    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if loginView.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            let height = keyboardSize.height
            self.loginView.frame.origin.y -= height
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to know how can I avoid subview down when I click textfield while subview is up.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the y-origin of view to zero when keyboard is down.
When you tap the other textField while keyboard is open this is .
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if loginView.frame.origin.y == 0{
            let height = keyboardSize.height

            self.loginView.frame.origin.y = -height
        }

    }

}

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if loginView.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            let height = keyboardSize.height
            self.loginView.frame.origin.y = 0
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to moving subview up to the top of self.view, I just want to moving subview up as much as keyboards height. And thanks but your suggestion didn't work as I expected, same with mine.

Comment: My code will move the view to upward as per height of the keyboard.
By default your y-origin of keyboard will be 0 and when keyboard will comes up let suppose the height is 100 so your view should place at -100 y-origin so does my code do.
My code will move the view to 100 points above no matter what was his last origin. But you was moving up the view to move 100 points upward from his previous y position.
So i just remove += with (- height) it will not subtract the y, it will just negate you y value.